# Laravel Collection Where Index

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

i have this collection below

```
[
   {
      "id":"6ad91b63-d964-4155-b16a-47fc246b6aa3",
      "content":"",
      "to":[
         "6ea94472-7db6-4d66-a485-30f99d46d039",
         "37c61b0b-2b75-4652-9ee9-b8d54fde3fe9",
         "335e9ee7-02ff-494d-89e9-b69b76d0504b",
         "7f67f3aa-7fdf-461c-aaf9-90293067363f",
         "a30477c8-256c-4ba8-aa69-22d7190516dd"
      ],
      "type":"berita",
      "created_by":"363b75f2-8f01-422d-a3cb-ea501d9b5edd",
      "created_at":"2022-01-12T18:22:51.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2022-01-12T18:23:47.000000Z"
   }
]
```

and i would like to find by columns "to" where "to" is value that i define. I was trying to use where collection but still get nothing. Here's my eloquent calls

```
$feed = Feed::latest()
             ->get()
             ->where('to','a30477c8-256c-4ba8-aa69-22d7190516dd');
```

Comment: the `to` element is an array so its not going to match a single string value ... are you looking for `whereIn` ?

Comment: i did try whereIn but still get nothing. the "to" element is actually accessor from model that contains serialize. I transform to unserialize and collection in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `filter` directly (which `where` uses):

```
$collection->filter(fn ($item) => in_array('a30477c8-256c-4ba8-aa69-22d7190516dd', $item->to))
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter) - `filter`

[PHP.net Manual - Function Reference - Arrays - Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - `in_array`

Comment: can u show the full code?

Comment: that is the code ... calling `filter` on the collection

Comment: oh okay, now it works. thank you!

Comment: np, good luck and enjoy Laravel